# How to order String format dates in ascending order?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

Here is my table that select Dates in string format

```
----------
SaleDate
---------- 
Jan 14
Feb 14
Mar 14
Nov 13
Dec 13
---------
```

And, I want these selected should be in Ascending order as,

```
----------
SaleDate
---------- 
Nov 13
Dec 13
Jan 14
Feb 14
Mar 14
---------
```

How could i get dates in ordered manner please help me.

Comment: please show the sql you are using to format and table schema

Comment: Obvious thing to do is to stop storing dates as strings. SQL Server has several decent data types for dealing with dates. The string types aren't in that set.

Comment: SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),6),6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is to use case when in the order by

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([SaleDate] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([SaleDate])
VALUES
    ('Jan 14'),
('Feb 14'),
('Mar 14'),
('Nov 13'),
('Dec 13');


select * from table1
Order by
        cast(substring(saledate,5,2) as int),
    case 
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Jan' then 1
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Feb' then 2
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Mar' then 3
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Apr' then 4
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='May' then 5
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Jun' then 6
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Jul' then 7
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Aug' then 8
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Sep' then 9
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Oct' then 10
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Nov' then 11
        when substring(saledate,1,3)='Dec' then 12
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is highly advised to not store date values as varchar values.
Anyways

```
select * from dateTable
order by cast(('01 '+ saleDate) as datetime) asc
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f799/2)

Comment: Ya, I know MHasan but 'Mar 13' type of date have to show dynamically that is why all i need to do this

Answer (score 0):

**Use below Query**

```
select a.SaleDate  from  (
select SaleDate
,Case WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'JAN' THEN 1
          WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'FEB' THEN 2
          WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'MAR' THEN 3 
           WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'APR' THEN 4 
           WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'MAY' THEN 5 
           WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'JUN' THEN 6 
        WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'JUL' THEN 7 
        WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'AUG' THEN 8 
        WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'SEP' THEN 9 
           WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'OCT' THEN 10 
           WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'NOV' THEN 11
          WHEN substring(SaleDate,1,3) = 'DEC' THEN 12            END  AS MON
          , Substring(SaleDate,len(SaleDate)-2,len(SaleDate))          AS YEAR1   
           from Table1 
            )   a order by YEAR1,MON
```